# How to get and display only checked items in joomla component

Tags: php, web, joomla, components

I have problem about joomla component development, I already created joomla component and I want to add a "print" feature to print the selected / checked items only on items listed in current displayed view of my component. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you have to display popup with selected items only. here u run javascript window.print(). Now selected item will print